# Why do I need Scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, enums

What exact benefit would I be getting by using Scala's Enum over not using it.

```
object Colours extends Enumeration {
  val Red, Blue, Green = Value
}
```

Why can't I just use this as :

```
 object Colours{
      val Red = "Red"
      val Blue = "Blue" 
      val Green = "Green"
}
```

I agree its a bit verbose, but I don't have to do a toString whenever I have to use it. Are there any better reasons to use Enums?
My question is: 
1)Should we use Enums just because its a Good practice?
2)Are there any performance consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [summarize](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html)

You get these benefits from `Enum`

- You have indexing
- You have predefined name
- You can iterate
- You can compare ordering
- You can iterate members.

Not to mention `Enum` has these problems

- Enumerations have the same type after erasure.
- There’s no exhaustive matching check during compile.
- They don’t inter-operate with Java’s enum.

Answer (score 3):

1. The real question is "why is it a good practice?". When using a type system, you shrink the possibility of buggy code. You would prevent bugs like:

   ```
   showColor("green") // wrong casing

   color match {
     case "Green" => // 
     case "Pink" => // invalid color
   } // match didn't include all possibilities (exhaustiveness)
   ```

   Of course, you can always use the vals you defined instead of literal strings, but without types there's nothing enforcing that.
2. Performance wise - probably not a huge difference unless it's in some tight loop